# how to send the basic authorization with username and password and auth type as basic in adapter-impl js file

Tags: javascript, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, ibm-integration-bus

how to send the basic authorization with username and password and auth type as basic in adapter-impl js file. I have already set the value in adapter.xml file, but it is not working fine, that's why I am setting it in adapter-impl.js file. This value is needed by IBM integration bus. I am connecting mobile first adapter to IBM integration bus. I need to send the username and password without encoding.

```
var input = {
    method: 'post',
    returnedContentType: 'json',
    path: '',
    headers: {
        Authorization: {
            'Basic .....'
        }
    }

};

return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
```

Comment: You should encode your auth string as  : "Basic " + (username + ":" + password). You typically encode the username:password combination. Strange that you mention it is not to be encoded

Comment: @ramachandran, will u give the exact syntax which we will use in mobilefirst adapter-impl.js file

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the authentication protocol in the adapter XML file.

For example:

`<authentication>
    <basic/>
    <serverIdentity>
        <username> ${DOMAIN\user} </username>
        <password> ${password} </password>
    </serverIdentity>
</authentication>`

For more information you can visit 
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_http_adapter_connect_pol.html